# VUGen error while replaying or debugging a script

Tags: performance-testing, loadrunner, vugen

I am using LoadRunner 12.60 version on Windows 10. The VUGen was working fine but lately while Replay or Debug I am getting the attached error pop up message - "UTT Debugger domain error". I have uninstalled and installed the software, tried to run VUGen as administrator but nothing worked. Kindly help in resolving this issue.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Could you please check the "Programs and Features" of Control Panel on Windows 10.
Please try to install Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Redistributable Package (x86/x64).

Answer (score 0):

The only option for this error it below -

1. Restart the machine
2. uninstall the installed software
3. download latest copy from the microfocus link
4. Reinstall the Load runner again.

Note : Do not use the previous downloaded copy for installation